# Resharper not working with universal apps project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, win-universal-app

Resharper does not seem to work at all in the shared project of a universal app project in Visual Studio 2013.

Example: right clicking a method or property and selecting "Find usages" always returns "Usages of xxx were not found" even if there are many references to the method or property in the shared project.

Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: which version of Resharper are you having trouble with?

Comment: appears to be a bug in the Resharper Bug tracker, http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-413390

Comment: Andrew, I'm using Resharper 8.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Update to Resharper 9 - No issues with it any more apart from Resharper complaining that styles don't exists sometimes.